# Recusively trying to find file within folder using keyword (VBA-Access)

Tags: vba, recursion, directory

I am creating an vba-access application with a drop down box Combo_History that gives the user the ability to launch a .pdf file from a sub-folder within a main folder called "Scanned Work Orders (Archives)". What I am trying to do is use a certain number called an "M" number(M number because every number starts with an M ex: M765196) to find this file without using a specific sub folder here is what i have so far:

---

Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder("T:\Scanned Work Orders (Archives)") 

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    If oFile = Combo_History.Value Then
            Application.FollowHyperlink ("T:\Scanned Work Orders (Archives)" & oFile)

        End If
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile = Combo_History.Value Then
            Application.FollowHyperlink ("T:\Scanned Work Orders (Archives)" & oFile)

        End If
    Next oFile
Loop
```

The problem is it gets stuck in an infinite loop because it cannot find the .pdf with the keyword name M765196 even though it is in that folder. Is there something im missing? Or an easier way to find the .pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm adding a second answer here because solving for a wildcard differed more than I anticipated from the original.

Searching for files using a wildcard isn't difficult, but it comes with some implications, such as returning a list of results instead of a single result. In addition, I fortunately ran into a permissions error on one of my subfolders which caused me to think about how to handle that situation.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private recurseDepth As Integer

Sub test()
    Dim rootFolder As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim resultFiles() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    rootFolder = "C:\Temp"
    filename = "*.pdf"

    If FindFiles(rootFolder, filename, resultFiles) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(resultFiles)
            Debug.Print Format(i, "00") & ": " & resultFiles(i)
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print "No files found!"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FindFiles(thisFolder As String, filespec As String, _
                          ByRef fileList() As String) As Integer
    '--- starts in the given folder and checks all files against the filespec.
    '    the filespec MAY HAVE A WILDCARD specified, so the function returns
    '    an array of full pathnames (strings) to each file that matches
    '      Parameters:  thisFolder - string containing a full path to the root
    '                                folder for the search
    '                   filespec   - string containing a single filename to
    '                                search for, --or--
    '                                string containing a wildcard string of
    '                                files to search for
    '        (result==>)fileList   - an array of strings, each will be a full
    '                                path to a file matching the input filespec
    '         Returns:  (integer) count of the files found that match the filespec
    On Error GoTo Error_FindFile
    Static fso As Object
    Static pathCollection As Collection
    Dim fullFilePath As String
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oSubfolder As Object

    '--- first time through, set up the working objects
    If recurseDepth = 0 Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set pathCollection = New Collection
    End If
    recurseDepth = recurseDepth + 1

    '--- focus on the given folder
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(thisFolder)

    '--- first test if we have permissions to access the folder and
    '    if there are any files in the folder
    On Error Resume Next
    If oFolder.Files.Count > 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            '--- loop through all items in the folder. some are files and
            '    some are folders -- use recursion to search the subfolders
            For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
                If oFile.Name Like filespec Then
                    pathCollection.Add oFolder.Path & "\" & oFile.Name
                End If
            Next oFile
            For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
                FindFiles oSubfolder.Path, filespec, fileList
            Next oSubfolder
        Else
            '--- if we get here it's usually a permissions error, so
            '    just skip this folder
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_FindFile

Exit_FindFile:
    recurseDepth = recurseDepth - 1
    If (recurseDepth = 0) And (pathCollection.Count > 0) Then
        '--- pull the paths out of the collection and make an array, because most
        '    programs uses arrays more easily
        ReDim fileList(1 To pathCollection.Count)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To pathCollection.Count
            fileList(i) = pathCollection.Item(i)
        Next i
    End If
    FindFiles = pathCollection.Count
    Exit Function

Error_FindFile:
    Debug.Print "Error (" & Err.Number & "): " & Err.Description & _
                        " on " & oSubfolder.Path
    GoTo Exit_FindFile

End Function
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for your help. It's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop setup didn't lend itself very well to recursion in looking for the file. The code below should work for you.

Also, you're using late-binding for your FileSystemObjects - which is perfectly fine. But the way you have them declared causes them all to be evaluated as Variants. It may be a pain, but it's better to break out each variable `Dim` on as separate line and to exactly specify what type it should be.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim rootFolder As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim fullpath As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    rootFolder = "C:\Users\user\Documents"
    filename = "testfile.txt"

    fullpath = FindFile(fso, rootFolder, filename)
    Debug.Print "file is ";
    If Len(fullpath) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "FOUND! : " & fullpath
    Else
        Debug.Print "NOT found. Go look for it yourself!"
    End If
End Sub

Function FindFile(fso As Object, thisFolder As String, filename As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Error_FindFile
    Dim fullFilePath As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oSubfolder As Object

    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(thisFolder)

    '--- first check if the file is in the current folder
    fullFilePath = oFolder.Path & "\" & filename
    If fso.FileExists(fullFilePath) Then
        '--- we're done, nothing more to do here
    Else
        '--- the file isn't in this folder, so check for any subfolders and search there
        fullFilePath = ""
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            Debug.Print "looking in " & oSubfolder.Path
            If FindFile(fso, oSubfolder.Path, filename) <> "" Then
                '--- found the file, so return the full path
                fullFilePath = oSubfolder.Path & "\" & filename
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oSubfolder
    End If

Exit_FindFile:
    FindFile = fullFilePath
    Exit Function

Error_FindFile:
    '--- we'll probably get mostly permission errors, so just skip (or log, or print out)
    '    the permission error and move on
    If Err.Number = 70 Then
        Debug.Print "Permission error on " & oSubfolder.Path
    End If
    GoTo Exit_FindFile

End Function
```

Comment: Now another question is if it is possible to find a file using this method with only a partial name lets say instead of the full "M" number I only have M76  instead of M765196. Is that possible?

Comment: You're asking about a wildcard search, and yes that is possible but there are implications you'll have to handle. Clearly, you can find zero, one, or many files that match the partial name `"M76*` and the matches can be in different folders of the directory tree. The `FileExists` function only works for a single file, so a better option is loop and check each filename against your wildcard string using `If thisFilename Like "M76*" Then ...`.

Comment: I tried this and it seems that the loop still isn't finding the file here is the code I used: If filename Like Me.Combo_History.Value Then 'Code from above End If Next oSubfolder

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/recursive_folder_search.html) suggests the following technique for finding a wildcard recursively:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    RecursiveDir colFiles, "C:\Photos\", "*.jpg", True

    Dim vFile As Variant
    For Each vFile In colFiles
        Debug.Print vFile
    Next vFile
End Sub

Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                             strFolder As String, _
                             strFileSpec As String, _
                             bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop

        'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

End Function

Public Function TrailingSlash(strFolder As String) As String
    If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = strFolder
        Else
            TrailingSlash = strFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to contribute to PeterT's solution (second answer)! It appears I don't have enough points to comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.

I tested the solution and it works, but it has some (minor) bugs! I didn't test it on a server with complicated privileges, but I'll eventually have to do that in the near future!

- If the startFolder is empty (no files, but subfolders) the function doesn't continue to search in startFolders' subfolders.
- Search for A*.pdf and a*.PDF will not give the same result. Given the fact that Windows file system is case insensitive, it's wise to have case insensitive search. Perhaps it won't work on MAC?!

In addition, I added two (optional) extra parameters, code for garbage collection and early binding for FSO objects (I prefer that!):

- boolean subFolders - if false the function will not search beyond the
  startFolder
- boolean fullPath - if false the function will return only file names    without the path; useful (at least to me) especially if subFolders=false.
- After the search finishes (recurseDepth = 0) all objects are set to    Nothing.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function FindFiles( _
    ByVal startFolder As String, _
    ByVal fileSpec As String, _
    ByRef fileList() As String, _
    Optional ByVal subFolders As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal fullPath As Boolean = True) _
  As Long
    '--- starts in the given folder and checks all files against the filespec.
    '    the filespec MAY HAVE A WILDCARD specified, so the function returns
    '    an array of files with or withour full pathnames (strings) to each file that matches
    '      Parameters:  startFolder - string containing a full path to the root
    '                                folder for the search
    '                   fileSpec   - string containing a single filename to
    '                                search for, --or--
    '                                string containing a wildcard string of
    '                                files to search for
    '        (result==>)fileList   - an array of strings, each will be a full
    '                                path to a file matching the input filespec
    '                   subFolders - include subfolders in startFolder
    '                   fullPath   - true=>fullFile path; false=>fileName only
    '         Returns:  (integer) count of the files found that match the filespec

    Dim fullFilePath As String
    Dim Path As String

    Static fso As FileSystemObject
    Static pathCollection As Collection
    Dim oFile As file
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oSubfolder As Folder

    On Error GoTo Error_FindFile

    '--- first time through, set up the working objects
    If recurseDepth = 0 Then
        Set fso = New FileSystemObject ' CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set pathCollection = New Collection
    End If
    recurseDepth = recurseDepth + 1

    '--- focus on the given folder
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(startFolder)

    '--- first test if we have permissions to access the folder and
    '    if there are any files in the folder
    On Error Resume Next
    If oFolder.files.Count > 0 Or oFolder.subFolders.Count > 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            '--- loop through all items in the folder. some are files and
            '    some are folders -- use recursion to search the subfolders
            If fullPath Then
              Path = oFolder.Path & "\"
            Else
              Path = ""
            End If
            For Each oFile In oFolder.files
'              If oFile.name Like fileSpec Then
              If LCase(oFile.name) Like LCase(fileSpec) Then
                pathCollection.Add Path & oFile.name
              End If
            Next oFile
            If subFolders Then
              For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.subFolders
                FindFiles oSubfolder.Path, fileSpec, fileList, subFolders, fullPath
              Next oSubfolder
            End If
        Else
            '--- if we get here it's usually a permissions error, so
            '    just skip this folder
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_FindFile

Exit_FindFile:
    recurseDepth = recurseDepth - 1
    If (recurseDepth = 0) Then
      If (pathCollection.Count > 0) Then
        '--- pull the paths out of the collection and make an array, because most
        '    programs uses arrays more easily
        ReDim fileList(1 To pathCollection.Count)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To pathCollection.Count
            fileList(i) = pathCollection.Item(i)
        Next i
      End If
      FindFiles = pathCollection.Count
      Set fso = Nothing
      Set pathCollection = Nothing
      Set oFile = Nothing
      Set oFolder = Nothing
      Set oSubfolder = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Function
Error_FindFile:
    Debug.Print "Error (" & Err.Number & "): " & Err.Description & _
                        " on " & oSubfolder.Path
    GoTo Exit_FindFile
End Function
```