# VBA loop through folder (mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, loops

I'm new to VBA, but I'm trying.

In a Excel for Mac 2011 workbook named "DataFile.xlsm" (which is stored on a shared network drive), I need a macro that clears the current contents of sheet 1 (named "Data"), then loops through an identified folder that is also on the shared network drive (& its subfolders) to find any excel workbook with a name starting with "*Info Sheet*". For each such workbook, I need to copy Sheet 1 C2:C12, transpose those cells, and paste them into Sheet 1 (named "Data") of the "DataFile" in a new row, columns A:K.

I have messed around with DIR and MacID stuff but can't figure it out. As a result, I can only get this to work at the worksheet level (all data inside one workbook) but I need it to work at the workbook level (all data inside one folder).

Please help. I've spent many many hours on this and gotten nowhere.

Here is what I have that works at the worksheet level:

```
Sub copy_studentsheets_to_datasheet_withclearing()

Dim ws As Worksheet

'clear contents from target sheet
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("a3:k600").ClearContents
Range("a3:k600").ClearFormats

'copy specified range from each worksheet (other than the "Data" worksheet)     and paste and transpose to new row in Data worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Data" Then
    'do nothing
    Else
        ws.Select
        Range("C2:C12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Data").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:K1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

Comment: I answered a similar question just now and solved the Find Files part of your problem [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385523/recusively-trying-to-find-file-within-folder-using-keyword-vba-access/31479037#31479037). I'm hoping this answer will work for you on Mac as well, though I can't test it.